# Does order of cosets matter?

Tags: group-theory

If I have worked out the distinct left hand cosets of a subgroup $H=\{e,a,b\}$ as

$eH=\{e,a,b\}, cH=\{c,d,f\}, gH=\{g,h,i\}, jH=\{j,k,l\}$

and the distinct right hand cosets as

$He=\{e,a,b\}, Hc=\{c,f,d\}, Hg=\{g,h,i\}, Hj=\{j,l,k\}$

Take $H$ to be subgroup of $G(\{e,a,b,c,d,f,g,h,i,j,k,l\},\circ)$. Can we take this subgroup to be normal, as the order of the sets are irrelevant?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can; the left and right cosets are the same.